# In Ansible, what is the variable denoting the non-root login user?

Tags: ansible

When I use `{{ ansible_user_id }}` in an Ansible script, it malfunctions whenever the script is executed using `become=true`, and always got cast into `root`.

I need to cast it into the real login user that login into the remote OS. What variable should I use in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

`ansible_ssh_user` contains the name of the connecting user.

---

**Other ways/clarification**

`ansible_user_id` contains the user executing the `setup` task (or used implicitly when `gather_facts: true`), so:

1. you can set `gather_facts: false` and then execute `setup` with `become: false`, or
2. you can add a play just to gather facts without `become: true` (or with `become: false`).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I never saw this in the document